# Track how often Junit test hast been run

Tags: jenkins, junit

I am currently learning about JUnits and Jenkin.
I was wondering, if there is a way to track how often a Junit test has been run. I couldn't find anything on Jenkins. And I don't thing it is possible within the JUnit test to track the number of times it has been run. Or am I wrong?
Do you have any idea how I could track that?

Thanks :)

Comment: Tangential, but why?

Comment: Depending on how often a test failed, I want to give more specific feedback on why it failed

Comment: More specific than what? A given test is only run once, and the test output should contain all the relevant information. IMO tests should be runnable locally as well since that allows test isolation and much faster iteration.